# PPA with latest PHP 5.3.x branch for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ppa, php

Is there a PHP 5.3.x PPA for 12.04?

Comment: You want 5.3 not 5.5?

Comment: Yes, I need 5.3.24 or newer (5.3.27 .. 5.3.28)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several PPA s with PHP 5.3.X for Ubuntu 12.04.

1. [ppa:sjinks/x3m](https://launchpad.net/~sjinks/+archive/x3m)
2. [ppa:team-mayhem/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~team-mayhem/+archive/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75)
3. [ppa:rip84/php5](https://launchpad.net/~rip84/+archive/php5)
4. [ppa:skettler/php](https://launchpad.net/~skettler/+archive/php)